# Need advice pertaining to applescript automation

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to write a program that does the following...

- Reads a line of text from textedit that contains only a series of URLs (each on a seperate line).
- Goes to that URL in the current page on my web browser.
- Makes two page clicks on the same location of the loaded page.
- Hits the "Enter" button
- Repeats from the first step

I am a beginner at applescript... but can learn anything needed to complete this project. Could someone show me an example of the code that I am trying to write?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. unfortunately you are not going to get much help because from the way your post reads it sounds like your asking for someone to do the work for you, you should get an idea of how to do this can post when you get stuck. So go find out how to read a text file in applescript that i'll be your first step

Answer (score 0):

```
set urls to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069198
http://stackoverflow.com"
--set urls to read "/tmp/input.txt" as «class utf8»

repeat with u in paragraphs of urls
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        open location u
        delay 1
        tell document 1
            repeat while do JavaScript "document.readyState" is not "complete"
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
            do JavaScript "document.querySelectorAll('#hlogo a')[0].click()"
        end tell
    end tell
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
end repeat
```